# How to disable fullscreen button in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen

[image]

How can I disable the fullscreen button in WebView? When I press this button:

```
onShowCustomView(View pView, CustomViewCallback pCallback)
```

in `WebChromeClient` will be call and cause some issue. How can I disable it?

Comment: fixed typos; fixed formatting

Answer (score 0):

Just do not override onShowCustomView in your WebChromeClient.
WebViewChromium enables fullscreen support if onShowCustomView and onHideCustomView are implemented in WebChromeClient successors. (Here is source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java#1347)